# Trying to assert role = Button when using a dyanmic span id

Tags: selenium

I am trying to verify that there is a button on the page named Select. The Select button has a dynamic span id.

This is what firebug is showing me:

```
span id="dijit_form_Button_18" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_18_label" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;"
```

Here is my code:

```
Assert.assertEquals("button",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Select']")).getAttribute("role"));
```

Comment: What problem are you running into? Are you facing any error?

Comment: @the_coder null is returned

Comment: You mean nullpointer exception? if so please mention the error in the question.

Comment: What about using: `//button[@name='Select']/span`? It should do the same? Also check case sensitivity. Is there difference between 'Select' and 'select'?

Comment: Im trying to retrieve the attribute of a dynamic ID

Answer (score 0):

If there is no good Xpath or CSS Selector solution, the method that always works is some visual check with [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/) or [Kantu](https://kantu.io/sikuli).

SikuliX automates anything you see on the screen of your desktop computer running Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. It uses image recognition powered by OpenCV to identify and control GUI components. This is handy in cases when there is no easy access to a GUI's internals or the source code of the application or web page you want to act on. It can be [combined with Selenium](http://www.devengineering.com/blog/testing/how-integrate-sikuli-script-selenium-webdriver).